# Drupal Custom Login Page Using Zen Sub-theme

Tags: hooks, users, theming

I have a custom Login Page in my website

I am using Zen for my themes.

I already have the Login page using the naming convention (e.g xxx--xxxx--tpl.php) but I can't display my form in this page.

here is my cpde

```
page--user_block--login.tpl.php:

<table class="body_login">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="gre"><div class="green_skin" ></div></td>
                        <td class="gre1"><div class="green_1_skin"></div></td>
                        <td class="cen">
                        <div class="alle" style="width:450px;">
                        <div class="modal-login">
                            <div class="modal-login-header">
                                <p>ONREVUE LOGIN</p>
                                <div class="icon-lock"></div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="content_my">


 /****This is where I want to display the form ***/

</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="data_d"><p class="other_p"><a href="#">Register</a><span>|</span><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p></div> 
                        <div style="clear:both;">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="gre1"><div class="green_1_skin"></div></td>
                        <td class="gre"><div class="green_skin"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

My Template.php code

```
function Alphasys_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
$hooks = zen_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path);
 // Add your theme hooks like this:
/*
  $hooks['hook_name_here'] = array( // Details go here );
*/

$hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
  'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
       'template' => 'page--user_block--login',
);

 // @TODO: Needs detailed comments. Patches welcome!
 return $hooks;
  }

  function Alphasys_preprocess_user_login_block(&$vars) {
  // Modify the text of the submit button
 $vars['form']['submit']['#value'] = t('Login Now!');

  $vars['form_markup'] = drupal_render($vars['form']);
}
```

I don't know what's the problem with the Code but it seems I can't make to work...

I already tried to put

```
<?php echo $form_mackup ?>
```

in my page--user_block--login but doesn't work.. I already tried to clear the cache..
but it is not working either..

Please help me...Responses are much appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you're confusing the login block with the login page in the preprocess function and tpl names

try

```
function Alphasys_preprocess_user_login(&$variables) {
  //a capitalized theme name?
  $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render($variables['form']);
}
```

then change the

```
$hooks['user_login_block']
```

to

```
$hooks['user_login']
```

and drop in your print statement into the tpl

```
<?php print $rendered ?>
```

and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks...I do now figured what's my problem with my code...but I can't see any fields e.g username field, password field when I try to print $rendered in my tpl...

 `'variables' => array('form' => NULL)`...it this the problem ? since I am using Drupal 7

MY question also..is why is it that the form there is null?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm more familiar with D6 than D7.  Looks like others have had this issue, see http://drupal.org/node/1072294
maybe try changing the hook_theme declaration to use 'render element' rather than 'arguments' and try and print that out?  so something like `'render element' => 'form'` and `<?php print $form ?>` .  Sorry I can't be more help...

Comment: also, look to drupal.org/node/1089656
it appears that D7 uses '--' in place of '-', so you could possibly add a page--user.tpl.php along with a page--user--login.tpl.php to get it picked up